# Sending mail to the user email address- Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to send an email to the user who has just entered his email address.

Like this,

```
$email = $request->email;

Mail::send('emails.info', $data, function ($message) {

    $message->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'My Email');

    $message->to($email)->subject('The subject');

});
```

But this returns an error:

> Undefined variable: email

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reference email within the closure use [use](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

```
$email = $request->email;

Mail::send('emails.info', $data, function ($message) use ($email) {

    $message->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'My Email');

    $message->to($email)->subject('The subject');

});
```